# LINQPad target framework and performance - how to configure?

Tags: c#, performance, mono, linqpad

I'm using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (full version) for learning C# and I really like it but I find the performance characteristics of code run unter LINQPad counter-intuitive and vexing, completely unlike the same code run in Visual Studio. For example, code using unsigned math is slightly faster than the same code using `int` in Visual Studio (as well it should be) but in LINQPad it is significantly slower.

Example:

```cs
static int n_mod_30_v0 (int n)
{
    return unchecked(n % 30);
}

static int n_mod_30_v1 (int n)
{
    return unchecked((int)((uint)n % 30));
}
```

Calling this on a million random non-negative integers in Studio shows the signed version as a few percent slower (because it needs several extra CPU instructions for adjusting negative results) but the difference is well below the measurement jitter. LINQPad has the unsigned version consistently slower (!) by 25% to 50%. This just doesn't make sense. And yes, the "/o+" button for release mode engaged and "compile with /optimize+" is selected in the preferences.

It is almost as if LINQPad were using a different (JIT) compiler - which might well be, since I have plenty of runtime versions installed including an old Mono. However, I could not find any configuration option for the target framework and I have no idea what's going on there.

Can LINQPad be configured to target a specific framework and/or CPU? Or are there other potential factors that could be responsible for the poor/anomalous code performance under LINQPad?

Targetting Mono can be useful when tuning submissions for coding challenge sites like SPOJ (which often run older versions of Mono) but on the whole LINQPad would be more useful with one of the MS frameworks, like 4.5.x.

`System.Environment.Version` values reported on this machine:

```
2.0.50727.8009  for Visual Studio with v2 .. v3.5
4.0.30319.17020 for Mono
4.0.30319.42000 for Visual Studio with v4 .. v4.6.1 and for LINQPad
```

Comment: What version of LINQPad and Visual Studio are you running? LINQPad 4 uses Framework 4 or 4.5, LINQPad 5 uses 4.6.

Comment: LINQPad 4.57.02 and VS 2015 (but the latter can be configured for many frameworks, obviously)

Comment: If you're using Framework 4.6 in Visual Studio and (implicitly) Framework 4.5 in LINQPad, that would definitely explain the performance differences you're seeing. I do believe you can force the framework version by editing LINQPad's `.config` file, as with all .NET applications.

Comment: @Ian: It seems that you hit the nail on the head. I had been using framework version 2.0.50727 in Visual Studio and LINQPad was using v4.0.30319. As soon as I switched Visual Studio to use version 4 or newer, performance dropped to less than half for `int` and even further for `uint`, exactly the same as in LINQPad. I also found the reason for the poor `uint` performance: the compiler emitted a DIV instruction instead of using multiplication with the inverse as it still did for `int`. The mind boggles...

Comment: @Ian: could you write this up as an answer please? Comments can't be accepted as an answer, and your answer is more difficult to find for others if it is hidden in a comment...

Comment: My Linqpad v4, only runs with .net 4, how to make it run under .net v4.5, I cannot see the async functions of `File` which are available in .net 4.5 ?